# In Win32, what does the size member (cb) name actually mean?

Tags: c, winapi

In quite a few Win32 structures you have to give the size of the structure to one of its members, in quite a few cases, the member that stores this is called `cb` or prefixed with this.

[DISPLAY_DEVICE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a `cb` member for size.

It's also used in names of certain types of messages, such as [CB_GETCURSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Perhaps in this case its for *ComboBox*.

In other places in Win32, the `cb` acronym (I assume?) is used as part of member names.

Such as [WNDCLASS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925944.aspx) which have `cbWndExtra` and `cbClsExtra`.

In `STARTUPINFO` you have it:

```
typedef struct _STARTUPINFO {
  DWORD  cb;
  LPTSTR lpReserved;
  LPTSTR lpDesktop;
  LPTSTR lpTitle;
  DWORD  dwX;
  DWORD  dwY;
  DWORD  dwXSize;
  DWORD  dwYSize;
  DWORD  dwXCountChars;
  DWORD  dwYCountChars;
  DWORD  dwFillAttribute;
  DWORD  dwFlags;
  WORD   wShowWindow;
  WORD   cbReserved2;
  LPBYTE lpReserved2;
  HANDLE hStdInput;
  HANDLE hStdOutput;
  HANDLE hStdError;
} STARTUPINFO, *LPSTARTUPINFO;
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says this:

> **cb**
>
> The size of the structure, in bytes.

I wondered if anyone knows what `cb` stands for or means?  If it does have meaning at all.

Perhaps someone knows the history of this, which may explain it.

Comment: Interestingly, though hungarian notation has been bastardized over time and completely missing the original intent, `cb` is the best example of the style where has `h`, and `dw` and `lp` are examples of bad hungarian notation.

Comment: ohhh Hungarian notation.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: It is worth noting that in the Win32 API, Hungarian notation _never_ had the original intent...

Comment: @Moo-Juice, Namely System vs Apps Hungarian Notation.

Comment: @rodrigo "cb" is Apps Hungarian. One of the few instances thereof in Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably stands for *count bytes*.

For example in the `STARTUPINFO` it should be initialized by you to `sizeof(STARTUPINFO)`. That way, the Windows internals will know which version of the struct you are using, as it has grown over the time.

In the other cases is simply a number of bytes.

Except in the ComboBoxes, there it stands for *Combo Box*.

Comment: They could have just called it `size`, no?

Comment: @TonyTheLion, `size` is a bit unclear whereas `count of bytes` or `cb` is definitive.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: Sure, somewhere I remember `cbSize`. But I'd personally use `sz` because it is usually initialized with the result of some `sizeof`.

Comment: @rodrigo, Except then it clashes with zero-terminated strings :p

Comment: @Tony *Size* is ambiguous. Particularly when you're dealing with character strings. The Windows API follows the convention to disambiguate the meaning by using `cb` (count of bytes) and `cch` (count of characters). This convention is used consistently and it shows up in places where disambiguation seems superfluous.

Comment: What I don't get is how `size` is ambiguous, though. Unless of course -- since you mentioned character strings -- one doesn't know the difference between `size` and `length`. A character string's length is measured in characters (which may have a size greater than 1 or even be variable-length) whereas its size, as the size of _every object_ (including structures) is always in bytes.

Comment: @Damon A [library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) in somewhat widespread use doesn't seem to know the difference between `size` and `length` either.

Answer (score 5):

`cb` in this case stands for

> Count of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Microsoft flavor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260976%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) of so called [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). In case of `cb` it's a count of bytes, as other answers already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

IInspectable is very right! cb means count of bytes and cch means count of charactors. see [StringCbPrintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [StringCchPrintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)